# Android application ImageView.Gone not consitant on device

Tags: android, textview, imageview, preferences

In the onResume I am getting references to the widgets that I need to change visibility on. The logcat shows that the settings from the prefs are coming back correctly (show_images, show_titles, show_descriptions). And the logcat shows that the if else is falling into each of the if else statements as it should. But on the device, 50% of the time or so some cards will appear blank on start. Some will appear totally blank after a pref change, and some of time it seems to work fine. I tried a clean, cleanbuild, and CleanUnInstall from the device with no luck. This is in the onResume. After calling the parent onResume and getting the pref.

```
    Log.i("INFO", show_images + "" + " "+ show_titles +" " + show_descriptions );
    //force the layout to load before changing properties
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(!show_images){
        Log.i("INFO", "show images false");
        image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else{
        Log.i("INFO", "show images true");
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

    if(!show_titles){
        Log.i("INFO", "show titles false");
        rTitle1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rTitle2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rTitle3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rTitle4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rTitle5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        Log.i("INFO", "show titles true");
        rTitle1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rTitle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rTitle3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rTitle4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rTitle5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(!show_descriptions){
        Log.i("INFO", "show desc false");
        rDescription1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rDescription2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rDescription3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rDescription4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rDescription5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        Log.i("INFO", "show desc true");
        rDescription1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rDescription2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rDescription3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rDescription4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rDescription5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why.... but converted the layouts from constraintLayout to linearlayouts. then the same onResume worked to control the visibility of the widgets. Adjustments were needed for layout issues but the data persistence worked the way that it was